# Установка ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Начал установку ubuntu, выбрал язык и все дальше вывалилось такое сообщение:

BusyBox v1.17.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.17.1-10ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)(initramfs) Ubable to find a medium containing a live file system, не подскажете что делать? ставлю 11.04 через диск, система стоит тоже ubuntu, необходимо просто все переустановить, а не получается...

Comment: Попробуйте для начала cd диск с убунту перезаписать...

Comment: Пробывал, точно также

Comment: Попробуй в BIOS по переключать пар-ры драйверов приводов жестких дисков и CD/DVD.

Comment: Пробывал, одно и тоже

Comment: А кстати, почему переустановить, что с той системой не так?

Comment: Очень тормозит, куча ошибок, обновлял систему до 11.10, то же самое. Решил переустановить ubuntu

Comment: Ноутбук? Какой HDD? Как подключен? пробовали загрузится через что нибудь другое, и прочекать HDD?

Comment: PC, 200гб, SATA, пробывал, тестировал все нормально. а вот ошибку пишет, а если через флешку загружаться, то все гуд, но через флешку я устанавливал и как видно очень криво встало, потому что не может так тормозить убунта. Гц 2,8, 2гб оперативы.

Answer (score 1):

при установке выбераем f6 убираем в строке quite splash добавляем pci=nomsiили all_generic_ide floppy=off irqpollэто проблема с обнаружением устройств.

Еще людям помогает отключение флопика в биосе, вручную, изменение параметров контроллеров (IDE SATA RAID), кто-то залез в комп, поменял местами шины- все нормально загрузилось, у кого-то 1 хард, он просто заменил шину, и все пошло.

тормозит она скорее всего из-за unity, у меня также было. Непонятно только почему не установить 12.04 LTS. Этот релиз достаточно хорошо проработан. При установке Ubuntu многие релизы мне приходилось ставить с изменением параметров, но с этим всё чётко, рекомендую.

Comment: Вычитал чтобы при установке не вылазила такая ошибка, то в bios поменять с APIC на PIC. Только я все не нахожу его в bios EFI BIOS Utility version 2.00.12.01.

Comment: очень может быть что этого у вас в биосе нету, сейчас они выпускаются малофункциональными.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте с флешки, это совсем несложно. Скачиваете программу UNetBootin, она не требует установки, показываете ей флешку, ISO-файл, она сама все запишет. Потом в Биосе повышаете приоритет загрузки со съемного носителя (он должен показать имя вашей флешки), и устанавливаете убунту. Имхо, так значительно проще, чем записывать на CD.